# 14.04 live whole screen flickers

Tags: system-installation, ati, live-usb, flicker

Trying to live boot(and install) ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso from a usb-stick and it gets to some login screen before the entire screen flickers or rather rerenders over and over. Machine is running a AMD R9 290x and the md5 hashes are matching.

I have not tried installing with any non-graphical installer as I'm partly a newbie to linux and as I'm reviewing it from an ease of use perspective.

[This](http://nona.st/flicker.mp4)  is what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot using `nomodeset`, some drivers have removed support for non-kernel mode setting. When you use `nomodeset`, the system will fall back to the VESA un-accelerated driver.

When you see the kernel list, press <kbd>e</kbd>, find the line ending with `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset`. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to boot